# How can I add files from different repository?

Tags: git

I have the following setup:

```
mkdir /base; cd /base

git init a
touch a/file.txt

git init b
cd b
git config core.worktree=/base
git add ../a/file.txt
```

I have a `/base` folder, which contains two repositories (`a` and `b`). Repo `a` contains just a file (not even commited). Repo `b` set the worktree to `/base` (where both repos resides). When I try to add the `file.txt` from repo `a`, it did not work (it just is not staged).

When I remove the `.git` folder from `a`, I can add the file.

```
rm -rf ../a/.git
git add -vvv ../a/file.txt
```

I am not exactly sure why this is the case. Maybe git prevent adding the file because it thinks it is a submodule? I've tried to prevent this with some submodule settings, but with no effect.

```
git config submodule.ignore all
git config submodule.active false
```

How can I trick git to forcefully add the file? (`-f` is just for ignored files and `-v` gives no information).

**EDIT**: I've managed this by temporary rename the `.git` folder with the following script:

```
# Check if there is a .git folder. If so, we need to temporary
# rename it, so we can track the file/folder.
GIT_DIR=
TRAVERSAL_PATH="$RESOURCE_TO_TRACK"
while [[ "$TRAVERSAL_PATH" != "/" ]]; do
    if [[ -d "$TRAVERSAL_PATH/.git" ]]; then
        GIT_DIR="$TRAVERSAL_PATH/.git"
        break
    fi
    TRAVERSAL_PATH="$(dirname $TRAVERSAL_PATH)"
done

[[ "$GIT_DIR" != "" ]] && mv "$GIT_DIR" "$GIT_DIR.keep"
git add -v -f "$RESOURCE_TO_TRACK"
[[ "$GIT_DIR" != "" ]] && mv "$GIT_DIR.keep" "$GIT_DIR"
```

`$RESOURCE_TO_TRACK` is the file of folder I want to add to the repository. After the initial add, my repo tracks changes and further add/commit work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

More precisely, the *path name* of a file in some commit *must* consist only of "descending" components, all of which reside in this repository, not in any other repository on the file system.  So if a file's path name is `../dir/file`, you can't add it, and a if a file's name is `dir/sub/file` where `dir/sub` contains a `.git`, you can't add it.

That last restriction is the submodule restriction:

> Maybe git prevent adding the file because it thinks it is a submodule?

It *is* a submodule, if it's in another directory with a `.git` in it.

You can bypass the submodule restriction using `git update-index`, but if you do, you're straying into dangerous territory:

```
$ git hash-object -w dir/sub/foo
e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391
$ git update-index --add --cacheinfo 100644,e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391,dir/sub/foo
```

What happens at this point isn't well defined if `dir/sub` really is a Git repository.  (I made a temporary pair of repositories to run these commands, and did not check any further here.)  Note that `../` is not valid as a path component:

```
$ git update-index --add --cacheinfo 100644,e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391,../sub/foo
error: Invalid path '../sub/foo'
fatal: git update-index: --cacheinfo cannot add ../sub/foo
```

Comment: I /can/, as mentioned in my question (rename/remove the .git folder). I've updated my question and add a answer to my problem.

Comment: Your method will probably work fine, just be aware that the sub-repo will think this is an untracked file unless/until you add it there, after which the two Gits will fight each other over the file. (That's what I mean by "isn't well defined": it's not a supported configuration either, so if things go wrong, you'll be on your own.) Note that nested sub-repositories will cause a problem for your script, which searches upwards only once, not all the way to the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

**Please read the important note at the bottom for a better alternative solution!**

## The literal answer to the question asked

Although you can't, as torek explained very well, there is a workaround.

You can version your file in `b` and copy it in `a` with a script. Here is your setup:

```
/base
|- a
|  |- .gitignore
|- b
   |- copy-file
   |- resources
      |- file.txt
```

- `/base/b/resources/file.txt` is your file that should belong to `/base/a` but versionned in `/base/b`.
- `/base/b/copy-file` is a script that copies the file to the correct location, don't forget to make it executable.
- `/base/a/.gitignore` ignores `file.txt` so that the copied file isn't versionned in `/base/a`.

Your workflow is the following:

1. Update all your branches.
2. Run `/base/b/copy-file` (possibly with git hooks), that will place an unversioned copy of your `file.txt` in `/base/a`.
3. Start working.

## Important note

I know it seems tempting to do it this way, because of reasons that pushed you into that current workflow of yours, but even if I answered your question as is, I also suggest you look into different approaches. For example:

- Keep the `copy-file` script in `/base`. There is probably a reason why you haven't done a single project with both those subfolders. That reason must be reusability. If you define the relative path of your `a` subdirectory in your `b` repository, that means they are somehow connected and interdependant. Which brings me to the next and better solution:
- **Use a package manager**! I'm sure your language has one of those fancy package managers, they're everywhere! So use `npm`, `pip`, `composer` or whatever your language works with, make your `b` sub-project require your `a` sub-project (or the other way around, it's not really clear what requires what in your question) and use namespaces to reference the distant file, when you need it in the other sub-project. You don't usually need to publish one of your sub-projects to use the official package manager website, you should have a way to include a Git repository.